# Does a Marx generator work good with low frequency?

Tags: generator

If it rectifies AC to DC it still has ripple frequency. For a Marx generator, should that ripple frequency be high or will it still work with low frequency? On, YouTube the flyback transformers powering Marx generators and voltage multipliers are always high frequency, like 30 kilohertz.

Answer (score 1):

[Marx generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marx_generator) are powered by DC.

[image]

<sub>Image from the [Wikipedia article on Marx generators.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marx_generator)</sub>

Marx generators don't rectify like the Cockcroft Walton multiplier does.  The Marx generator doesn't care how you get the DC voltage high enough.

The operating frequency of the circuit generating the DC for the Marx generator doesn't matter to the Marx generator because all it sees is the final DC output.

The Marx generator is at its heart nothing but a bunch of capacitors.  They will smooth the ripple from the DC high voltage source.

The resistor and capacitor for each stage forms a low pass filter.  If you know the values of R and C for the first stage, you can calculate the cutoff frequency of the filter.

As a practical thing, it doesn't really matter.  A Marx generator typically charges for much longer than the period of the ripple. The ripple averages out over the charging time.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the extra ripple at the first stage or few, might be an annoyance.  It is a lowpass filter structure, after all, so the ripple seen at each stage will drop along the chain.

Just set those first gaps wider to account for the peak ripple, no problem.